# Javascript .click() different for elements w/ same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, click

I'm pretty new to Javascript/Jquery and am implementing a real simple image carousel for practice and ran into a problem regarding Jquery's "click" method.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
$(document.getElementsByClassName("traverse")).click(function() {
    if(this.id = "left"){
        if (current == 0) {
            current = images.length-1;
        }
        else {
            current -= 1;
        }
    }
    else if(this.id = "right") {
        if(current = images.length-1) {
            current = 0;
        }
        else {
            current += 1;
        }
    }
    $(document.getElementById("image-view")).css("background-image", "url(" + images[current] + ")");
});
```

With this code there are no errors, but every time I click either the "#right" or "#left" button, they both run code as if "this.id = 'left'". While I understand I can simply separate the two and this will work fine, is there a way I can do it similar to what I have now where I'm applying this event to the class, but differentiating the behavior by the id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Typo

`==` to [compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators)

`=` to [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)

> Strict equal (===) Returns true if the operands are equal and of the
>   same type

```
if(this.id === "left"){
            ^
```

---

and better use

[class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('.traverse').click(function(){ .. });
```

---

Problem with your code

you are assign `this.id = "left"` every time in if condition so is condition is always true

```
if(this.id = "left"){
```

Comment: +1. Please consider using proper `===` for comparison since you know type of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're *setting* `this.id` *to* `left` by only using a single `=` sign. Try this:

```
$(document.getElementsByClassName("traverse")).click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.id === "left"){
```

and so on.

Comment: +1. Please consider using proper `===` for comparison since you know type of the result.